# MPI_Cart_create giving MPI_ERR_ARG

Tags: c, mpi

This is driving me nuts---I don't know what I am doing wrong. I have looked at the API over and over again. I know the signature of MPI_Cart_create:

```
int MPI_Cart_create(MPI_Comm comm_old, int ndims, int *dims, int *periods, 
               int reorder, MPI_Comm *comm_cart)
```

Here is my code:

```
MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &processCount);
MPI_Comm cart_com, old_com;
int ndims = 2;
int reorder = 0;
int dim_size[2], periods[2];
dim_size[0] = processCount; 
dim_size[1] = processCount;
periods[0] = 1;
periods[1] = 1;
old_com = MPI_COMM_WORLD;
MPI_Cart_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ndims, dim_size, periods, reorder, &cart_com);
```

I get the error:

```
[ubuntu:7975] *** An error occurred in MPI_Cart_create
[ubuntu:7975] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[ubuntu:7975] *** MPI_ERR_ARG: invalid argument of some other kind
[ubuntu:7975] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (your MPI job will now abort)
```

Even just a little hint would be nice....
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `processCount` processes, but you are trying to create a communicator that is `processCount` x `processCount` in size (yielding a total of `processCount`^2 processes). And, as the [documentation](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-1.1/mpi-11-html/node133.html) will tell you:

> The call is erroneous if it specifies a grid that is larger than the group size.

Try this:

```
dim_size[0] = processCount; 
dim_size[1] = 1;
```

Comment: We have a winner! Thank you very VERY much!

Comment: Does he actually need two dimensions for this? I would understand if we have a one-dimensional array (vector) dim_size[0] = ... but why do we need to put the 1 in the second dimension?

Comment: @rbaleksandar: True, if all you want is an `N*1` process matrix, then you can just have 1 dimension of size `N`. The OP clearly intends to use 2 dimensions though, but doesn't mention in what arrangement. So I took the trivial approach to highlight the simplest solution: the OP can most likely take it from here.

Answer (score -1):

int *dims and int *periods are pointers. You are sending array.

```
MPI_Cart_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ndims, dim_size, periods, reorder, &cart_com);
```

Try sending pointers.

```
MPI_Cart_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ndims, &dim_size, &periods, reorder, &cart_com);
```

Comment: Just changing the call didn't work....do I need to declare dim_size as a pointer, do malloc, and THEN pass it in?

Comment: Array names in C are pointers to the first element. Besides `&dim_size` is of type `int (*)[2]` (pointer to an integer array with 2 elements) and not `int *`.